Is it possible to rename the session cookie (PHPSESSID) to another value on the application level?
I know it is possible to change it in php.ini or .user.ini and such, but is it possible to rename the default session cookie name PHPSESSID to something else on the application level?
EDIT: If yes, how?

Yes, it's possible to rename the default session cookie name PHPSESSID to something else at the application level in Magento

@Jtidd, ok thanks. Should I have added how to do it? Obviously, that is what I want to know....

You can add session.name=M2-PHPSESSID to nginx.conf (see PHP_VALUE):
...

# PHP entry point for main application
location ~ ^/(index|get|static|errors/report|errors/404|errors/503|health_check)\.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_pass   fastcgi_backend;
    fastcgi_buffers 1024 4k;

    fastcgi_param  PHP_FLAG  "session.auto_start=off \n suhosin.session.cryptua=off";
    fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE "memory_limit=756M \n max_execution_time=18000 \n session.name=M2-PHPSESSID";
    fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 600s;

    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

...


Thanks, but I was looking for an answer on changing it on application level.
